# How best to persist arbitrary user data from a PAM module?

Tags: password-management

Is there a standard way for a PAM module to persist additional arbitrary data about each user, where that information is to be retrieved and updated in a later invocation of the same PAM module for the same user?

Comment: Help me here. What is unclear about this question? I assume that the concept of persisting data on a per-user basis is clear enough. I assume people agree that, if there's a standard way of doing something, then following the standard way is a good thing. But, to a significant percentage of the people who've read this question, the question is unclear. I don't dispute that. So what's unclear? Or have I  just put this question to the wrong audience?

Comment: Perhaps I can ask this a different way. Is what I am trying to do unclear? Or is it the why I want to do it that is unclear?

Comment: Question reworded. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, apart from the usual filesystem organisation.

From the modules I checked, most don't save anything persistently, but only read a static configuration from the module options or from some file. Of those that do, `pam_tally2.so` uses `/var/log/tallylog`, and `pam_pwhistory` uses `/etc/security/opasswd`.

However, `/etc` is supposed to be used only by static configuration, so `/var/lib` would probably be more correct for variable data. That said, you probably want to make the location of the files configurable.

I don't see much reason to use anything other than files as storage.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

> Obviously, a PAM module can implement any functionality it wants to.

...rather implies that you are not seeking advice on implementing a pam module.

> is there a standard way for a PAM module to persist arbitrary data

Implies you are writing a pam module.

I am not aware of anything within the [pam specification](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/pre/doc/rfc86.0.txt.gz) to persist data beyond authentication. The `pam_[get|set]_item()` and 
`pam_[get|set]_data()` functions provide a means for persisting data *during* authentication. The pam_env module provides a mechanism for exporting some of this data into the login shell/process.

You need to be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to achieve to get a proper answer here.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for information on how best to implement a PAM module. I don't just want something that works, I want something that works in the way people expect it to work, or at least, in a way that doesn't upset people.
More specifically, I'm looking to store some information when a user logs in, to be checked against at later logins.

Comment: That helps, but what are you wanting to store which is not already captured in utmp?

Comment: Just an extra integer. I'm thinking of adding an extra test of the strength of the user's password, and it would help to be able to track some metadata over time.